# A button gets out of the div

Tags: html, css

I have the following navbar -

```css
#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1 !important;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #20b7c2;
}

#Name {
  padding: 0px !important;
  top: 0px;
}

.openbtn {
  background-color: #20b7c2;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 0px;
  border: 1px white solid;
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: 50px !important;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.navbarButtons1 {
  background-color: #20b7c2;
  color: white;
  border: 0px;
  cursor: Default;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</button>
  <input class="navbarButtons1" type="button" value="Test" id="Name">
</div>
```

In it, the second button with the value "test" just overflows out of the div for no reason at all. I tried some things but they did not work. How to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It has height: 49px; and is offset from the top

Comment: @mplungjan I changed it, but it did not work.

Comment: exactly, as @mplungjan mentioned change the height in .navbarButtons1 {} to something like 40px; or less to fit as per your requirements.

Comment: This is an issue of different `vertical-align` for input and button. Set it to `top` for both of them.

Comment: just remove height from the class .navbarButtons1 it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `float: left` to each button.

```css
#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1 !important;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #20b7c2;
}

#Name {
  padding: 0px !important;
  top: 0px;
  float: left;
}

.openbtn {
  background-color: #20b7c2;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 0px;
  border: 1px white solid;
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: 50px !important;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 25px;
  float: left;
}

.navbarButtons1 {
  background-color: #20b7c2;
  color: white;
  border: 0px;
  cursor: Default;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</button>
  <input class="navbarButtons1" type="button" value="Test" id="Name">
</div>
```

Comment: In modern web development `float` should be not used.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Why? I never heard of this before... The tutorial I used to learn HTML used `float` openly... And its not outdated.

Comment: @ArchitGargi seems like some outdated tutorial from w3schools (one of the worst websited to go learn development from BTW). `flex` should be used instead

Comment: @ArchitGargi because just for example way too many novice developers come right here to StackOverflow straight with problems from w3schools.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan So? W3Schools has updated a lot since I saw it the first time. Its not at all bad

Answer (score 1):

Use display flex

```css
#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1 !important;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #20b7c2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#Name {
  padding: 0px !important;
  top: 0px;
}

.openbtn {
  background-color: #20b7c2;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 0px;
  border: 1px white solid;
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: 50px !important;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.navbarButtons1 {
  background-color: #20b7c2;
  color: white;
  border: 0px;
  cursor: Default;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</button>
  <input class="navbarButtons1" type="button" value="Test" id="Name">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `vertical-align: middle;` and **use `display: flex;`** on your  parent `#navbar` element instead .

Using `vertical-align: top;` is not the best solution.
Also, make sure to use the right `height` values, or rather don't set `height`s at all.

Example:

```js
const toggleMenu = () => {
  console.log("toggle menu!");
};

document.querySelectorAll(".openbtn").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu);
});
```

```css
/* QuickReset */ * {margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}

:root {
  --color-primary: #20b7c2;
}

#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1; /*!important should never be used.Just as a last resort.Study CSS specificity instead*/
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  display: flex;
}

button {
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.openbtn {
  border-right: 1px white solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <button type="button" class="openbtn">&#9776; <!-- STOP using inline onclick handlers. --></button>
  <button type="button">Test</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Doing it just removes the button completely from the div.